# Linear Algebra basis question

Tags: linear-algebra

here is the link to a screen shot I took. I don't understand why the first choice can't be the answer since it also has 3 pivot points just like the correct answer.

http://tinypic.com/r/nd8qv5/5

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix}10\\2\\3\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}-1\\8\\-7\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}-11\\6\\-10\end{bmatrix} = 0$$

Comment: ik after i reduced it i got 3 pivot points

Comment: nvm Im stupid. I was calculating with 1 instead of -1

Comment: If you know that there is only one correct answer then you can recognise that it must be the third one.

Answer (score 0):

One of the vectors can be written as a linear sum of the other two. This means that the vectors don't span the space. Or, in other words, not all points in the 3 dimensional space can be reached by considering a weighted, linear sum of the three vectors.

In contrast, neither one of the orthogonal vectors, $\bf{i}$, $\bf{j}$, $\bf{k}$ can be written in terms of the other.